# How to retrieve the Hash of a Signature using OpenSSL?

Tags: openssl, verify

I am trying to retrieve an Hash by entering the OpenSSL command :

```
openssl rsautl -verify -in SignS -pubin -inkey ServerPubKey -out HashRetrieved
```

Where SignS is my signature, ServerPubKey the public key and HashRetrieved the hash I want to retrieve with the command.

However, I get the following error :

```
The command rsautl was deprecated in version 3.0. Use 'pkeyutl' instead.
```

By then following the error, I proceed to do the following command :

```
 openssl pkeyutl -verify -in SignS -pubin -inkey ServerPubKey -out HashRetrieved
```

But then get the following error :

```
pkeyutl: No signature file specified for verify
```

What is the correct command to retrieve the Hash for the signature file using a public Key ?